# Instagram to TableView w/ RestSharp

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

Hello Im trying to load the individual names of people in my Instagram feed onto a UITableView using Xamarin.iOS. However it only shows the name of the classes as you can see here:

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Here is my request that I am using to try to pull the instagram feed:

```
var request = new RestRequest {RootElement = "data", Resource = "/users/self/feed"};
            request.AddParameter("access_token", instagramAccessToken);

            var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");

                client.ExecuteAsync<List<RootObject>>(request, response => {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Data);
                InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
                    // pass the data to the TableSource class
                    ((TableSource<RootObject>)table.Source).Data = response.Data;

                    // make the TableView reload the data
                    table.ReloadData();
                });
            });
```

Here is the class file for the incoming Instagram Feed:

```
    public class Pagination
    {
        public string next_url { get; set; }
        public string next_max_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int? id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comments
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<object> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum2
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string profile_picture { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Likes
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class LowResolution
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Thumbnail
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class StandardResolution
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Images
    {
        public LowResolution low_resolution { get; set; }
        public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
        public StandardResolution standard_resolution { get; set; }
    }

    public class From
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string profile_picture { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Caption
    {
        public string created_time { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public From from { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public string profile_picture { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string bio { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("[User: username={0}, website={1}, profile_picture={2}, full_name={3}, bio={4}, id={5}]", username, website, profile_picture, full_name, bio, id);
        }
    }

    public class LowResolution2
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class StandardResolution2
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Videos
    {
        public LowResolution2 low_resolution { get; set; }
        public StandardResolution2 standard_resolution { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public object attribution { get; set; }
        public List<object> tags { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Comments comments { get; set; }
        public string filter { get; set; }
        public string created_time { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public Likes likes { get; set; }
        public Images images { get; set; }
        public List<object> users_in_photo { get; set; }
        public Caption caption { get; set; }
        public bool user_has_liked { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
        public Videos videos { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the getCell method under the TableSource class:

```
    public class TableSource<RootObject> : UITableViewSource 
{
    public List<RootObject> Data { get; set; }
    protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource ()
    {
        Data = new List<RootObject> ();
    }

    public TableSource(List<RootObject> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        if (Data == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Data.Count;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // request a recycled cell to save memory
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Text = Data[indexPath.Row].data[0].user.username;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `List<RootObject>` to your TableSource.  Each RootObject has a data property that is a `List<Datum>`;  Each Datum has a User property, and each User has a username property.

So you want to do something like this (I'm arbitrarily grabbing the first Datum, this may not be correct)

```
cell.TextLabel.Text = Data[indexPath.Row].data[0].user.username;
```

Comment: unfortunately it says that '.data[0].user.username;' cannot be referenced I have edited the question to display the whole TableSource Class

Comment: You need to use the debugger to look at the data you are getting back and verify that it has all of the objects on it that you are expecting, and that they are getting deserialized correctly.

Comment: Well I was looking through the debugger and everything is going to each object. Could it be something to do with it being a list and not an array? @jason

Comment: in the debugger, look at each element of this expression (ie, start with Data[indexPath.Row]) and verify it is what you expect.  Then drill down piece by piece and verify it (Data[indexPath.Row].data, then Data[indexPath.Row].data[0], then Data[indexPath.Row].data[0].user, etc until you find the error.  This is just basic debugging on any platform

Comment: The problem is that when I try to type anything after Data[indexPath.Row] it doesnt come up as an option and would say that i cannot reference it. It is not that it is not loading onto a class, it is that when I type '.' data does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your least amount effort to display meaningful text would be to override the ToString() method on the DTO's you wish to display. You have already done this to User so if you want to show the user info just overrider the Datum class, something like this:

```
public class Datum
{
    ...
    override ToString()
    {
         return this.User.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this method however my table still looks like how it does in the first picture of the question

Comment: Did you add it to RootObject? It seems that is the collection type you are displaying on the list view.